# c#, MVVM, Command, ContextMenu Binding

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding

Столкнулся с проблемой.
Имеется внутри View

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <local:iEventControl>
       <local:iEventControl.ContextMenu>
         <ContextMenu>
           <MenuItem Header="Отобразить список"  Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
         </ContextMenu>
       </local:iEventControl.ContextMenu>
     </local:iEventControl>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

И внутри ViewModel такое

```
public RelayCommand ShowCommand { get; set; }

void InitCommands()
    {
      ShowCommand = new RelayCommand(
            x => Show(x),
            (can) =>
            {
                return can == null ? false :
                Directory.Exists(ApplicationPath.Groups + (can as Event).Persons + @"/") ?
                File.Exists(ApplicationPath.Groups + (can as Event).Persons + @"/" + "GroupList.dat")
                : false;
            });
    }
```

В (can) все время (при запуске страницы) заходит null. Когда же я выбираю в ListBox элементо и жмакаю правой кнопкой, то меню айтем с данной командой не доступен.

Директория и файл существуют.
Event - мой класс, в котором есть поле строковое Persons;
Команду видит, биндинг работает.

Также прикрепляю класс RelayCommand - paste.org.ru/?wu3n62

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема вот в чём.

У вас дана реализация `CanExecute`, но нет реализации `CanExecuteChanged`. Поэтому изменения `CanExecute` не подхватываются.

Есть несколько путей решения этой проблемы.

Во-первых, ваша реализация `RelayCommand` (это нестандартный класс, значит, вы берёте его из какого-то фреймворка или написали самостоятельно) может предоставлять возможность запустить `CanExecuteChanged`. Тогда вы должны сами реализовать логику, которая определяет эти обстоятельства, и «дёргает» `CanExecuteChanged` в нужный момент. Этот путь может быть сложен, если ваш параметр меняется со временем.

Во-вторых, вы можете в тот момент, когда по логике программы команда может активироваться или деактивироваться, вызвать вручную `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested`. После этого значение `CanExecute` будет перечитано.

---

У меня и правда `InvalidateRequerySuggested` не сработало на `RelayCommand`. Я поменял его на `RoutedUICommand`, и всё взлетело.

Смотрите. Во-первых, определяем нужную команду:

```
public class GlobalCommands : RoutedUICommand
{
    private GlobalCommands() { } // запрещаем создавать экземпляры снаружи

    public static GlobalCommands ShowStudents =
        new GlobalCommands() { Text = "Отобразить список студентов" };
    // сюда можно добавлять ещё команды
}
```

Затем, в главной `VM` создаём `CommandBinding`:

```
public IEnumerable<CommandBinding> SupportedBindings { get { return supportedBindings; } }
List<CommandBinding> supportedBindings;

void InitCommands()
{
    supportedBindings = new List<CommandBinding>()
        {
            new CommandBinding(
                GlobalCommands.ShowStudents,
                (sender, args) => ShowStudents(args.Parameter),
                (sender, args) => args.CanExecute = CanShowStudents(args.Parameter))
        };
}
// ...
void ShowStudents(object iEvent)
{
    if (iEvent is Event)
    {
        var _event = iEvent as Event;

        // загрузить конкретную группу
    }
}

bool CanShowStudents(object iEvent)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("CanShowStudents called");
    var ev = iEvent as Event;
    if (ev == null)
        return false;
    Debug.WriteLine($"CanShowStudents, persons = {ev.Persons}");
    return Directory.Exists(AppPathGroups + @"\" + ev.Persons) &&
            File.Exists(AppPathGroups + @"\" + ev.Persons + @"\" + "GroupList.dat");
}
```

Таким образом создаётся привязка команды к её реализации.

Затем, привязки нужно зарегистрировать, чтобы какой-нибудь UI-объект их обрабатывал. Например, окно. Для этого в App.xaml.cs пишем:

```
// вызывается на Application.Startup
void ApplicationStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = new ViewModel();
    foreach (var binding in vm.SupportedBindings)
        CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(Window), binding);

    var w = new Window1();
    w.DataContext = vm;
    w.ShowDialog();
}
```

И наконец, в UI пишем такое:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Отобразить список студентов"
              Command="{x:Static mvvm:GlobalCommands.ShowStudents}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

В таком варианте код работает.

Comment: Вот мой класс - http://paste.org.ru/?wu3n62, @VladD.
Использую также этот класс в другом месте по аналогичному принципу (CommandParametr != null, только в качестве параметра переходит ListBox.SelectedItem) и там CanExecute изменяется в зависимости от того выбран ли lbItem или нет.

Насчет ручной активации - кажется мне, что это не всем идеальное решение. К тому же команда забиндена на контекстное меню (код выше), тогда в каком случае вызывать вручную?

Спасибо

Comment: @bodynar: То есть при **фиксированном** `can` у вас значение `CanExecute` не может меняться, я правильно понял? (Класс лучше добавить в вопрос.)

Comment: can - просто название переменной в лямбда выражении. Либо же я вас не совсем понял.

Comment: @bodynar: Ну, для одного и того же значения `can` может ли вычисленное значение `CanExecute` меняться в течение пробега программы?

Comment: Нет, значение `CanExecute` вычисляться должно 1 раз, при выборке `ListBoxItem`, @VladD.
Т.е. `ListBoxItem` получил `RightClick`, выпало контекстное меню и команда должна быть доступна.

_Начинаю подумывать об изменении команды, убрать CanExecute и добавить в обработчик проверку аналогичную проверке в CanExecute_

Comment: @bodynar: А если тупо на `PreviewRightMouseDown` вызвать `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41044/discussion-between-bodynar-and-vladd).

Comment: Опробовал `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested` - безрезультатно, @VladD.

Также пробовал вызвать `Command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();` в событии наведения мыши на `MenuItem` - результат аналогичный.

_(не знаю почему - но в начале сообщения обращение к пользователю стирается)_

_Также не понимаю, почему вы, @VladD, не заходите в чатик_

Comment: @bodynar: Заработался :) Если никакие трюки не работают, может быть, выложите минимальный воспроизводящий код?

Comment: Куда залить проект, товарисч @VladD?

Comment: @bodynar: Даже не знаю, а какие есть варианты?

Comment: Напишите мне, добавив (собака)gmail(тока) _ком_ к моему нику, @VladD.
Либо какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: Проще всего файлообменник. Например, в архив и куда угодно. Хоть на rghost.